# UIView tab bar on top, like HTML on iPhone view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiview

I'm developing a **Hotel reservation iPhone application**.

I tab view that I mention below image. So I don't know how to search it even. :(

So does any one knows about how to get it to our application I mean Is their any controller to this. Or else how to code this. (Is it html coding??)

**Note** : I am using Xcode 4.2 and story board. :)

[image: Tab view]

Comment: Do you want it to work like a UITabBarController? Do you want to use one controller for each page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to use UISegmented Controls with custom background, and then create subviews that will switch when you hit the "details" / "Diner Reviews" buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a custom iOS tabbar control similar to what you've drawn

http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/bhtabbar